# How to embed the user registration template within the frontpage with Flask-security?

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

Flask-security provides a template for registering new users.

I want to include a form in the frontpage of my site for user registrations. Can I somehow embed flask-security template + endpoint/function in my home endpoint? Or do I have to create a new template and function from scratch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add `{% include "security/register_user.html" %}` to your homepage template. As long as you set the endpoint for registering users, it will work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, is there anyway to reuse also the view function that comes with the library to register users? Can I somehow inherit such function in the view function of my homepage?